# SSMS: Restore a DB from a .bak file located on another VM

Tags: virtual-machine, ssms, database-restore

I am working on a VM (say "abc123"). **SSMS** (SQL Server Management Studio) is installed on this machine. Now, on SSMS, I have connected another VM/server (say "def456"). I want to restore a DB using a .bak file located on server "def456".

Is it possible to access .bak file located on "def456".

**Note:** I can't configure "abc123" on SSMS and so taking a copy of .bak file on "abc123" won't help.